# In Liquibase is it OK to have an empty line on splitstatements?

Tags: sql, oracle, liquibase, oracle19c

In Liquibase is it OK to have an empty line on splitstatements?

Bellow I want to execute 2 statements:

```sql
--changeset me:1 runAlways:false runOnChange:false failOnError:true splitStatements:true endDelimiter:;
update my_table
set    col = 1
where  col is null;

alter table my_table modify col not null;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes it's ok to have an empty line in between multiple queries to be executed. `splitStatements` basically search for the provided end-delimeter and  splits multiple queries for execution. So having a new line would not cause any issue. The changeset snippet you provided in the question should work.

By default the value of `splitStatements` is set to `true` which splits the statements on `;`s. Have a look at `splitStatements` attribute in liquibase document [here](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/basic/sql-format.html).

Comment: ++1 gr8. Would you like to see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72989797/what-does-liquibase-splitstatements