# What benefit does liquibase "splitStatements" provide?

Tags: liquibase, liquibase-sql

liquibase version being used - org.liquibase:liquibase-core:3.8.2. (not pro version)

Liquibase documents ([1](https://docs.liquibase.com/change-types/sql.html) & [2](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/sql-format.html)) says below about `splitStatements` (defaults to true)

> Set to false to not have Liquibase split statements on ;'s and GO's.
> Defaults to true if not set

and

> Removes Liquibase split statements on ;'s and GO's when it is set to
> false. Default value is: true.

Another useful sof post i found - [In Liquibase is it OK to have an empty line on splitstatements?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67230550/4820101)

I understand - when splitStatements is true, liquibase splits the statements on `;` and `GO`

1. It not entirely clear what benefit `splitStatements` adds -  i.e if SQL statement are split on `;` (end delimiter) or not, what difference will it make - i.e if the statements are executed in a single query or multiple queries - won't the db handle the ";" based stuff anyway. This seems to be essential to understand. --could some one quote an example.
2. My current project has `splitStatements:false`. what advantages are we getting by disabling splitStatements. -any example would be greatly appreciated.

**------------------------question expanded after answer from @user13579**
below is an extract from a liquibase changelog file. This is what brought me to this question. It has `splitStatements:false` and a `;`s in script and it works. With `splitStatements:false` i would expect a error in this case and the answer I suppose also suggests an error in this case. The below is from production code so I am NOT sure how it works and the backend is POSTGREs. Can someone explain.

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset adam:001-users-001 failOnError:true splitStatements:false logicalFilePath:001-users.sql

CREATE TABLE sys_users
(
  user_id SERIAL,
  first_name character varying(64) NOT NULL,
  last_name character varying(64) NOT NULL,
  email character varying(255) NOT NULL
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE TABLE user_role
(
  role_id SERIAL,
  role_name character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  description character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  created_on timestamp(6) with time zone NOT NULL,
  created_by character varying(64) NOT NULL,
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```